# How to configure editorconfig so that there are white spaces on both sides of {} when I format the code

Tags: intellij-idea, format, editorconfig

How to configure editorconfig so that there are white spaces on both sides of `{}` when I format the code, eg:

```
import {match, NavLink}
```

from 'react-router-dom' became

```
import {   match, NavLink   }
```